# How do I configure the Emacs-like keyboard shortcuts in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

OS X has built in support for [many Emacs-like keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#text): for example, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the paragraph and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> moves the cursor to the end. How can I configure these shortcuts and add more of them?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @lanza Yes, I added an answer pointing at the documentation sources I found. Thanks for prodding me to finally post them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some good resources on how to add and configure these keyboard shortcuts:

- [A detailed exploration of these shortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/20090208024812/http://www.erasetotheleft.com/post/mac-os-x-key-bindings/) by Llew Mason, unfortunately only available now through the Wayback Machine.
- [A similar article](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html) by an anonymous author (I think) that includes some caveats about specific methods.
- [A GitHub repository](https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings) by Brett Terpstra that shows examples of some relatively complex key bindings.
- [A deep dive into the Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) by Jacob Rus. It’s a decade old now but I’m *guessing* that a lot of the information is still applicable to today’s macOS.